# django user registration

Tags: django, django-views

I have got a problem with registering user.

```
AttributeError at /users/register/
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'get'
```

The code is here: https://github.com/matiit/pym/blob/master/docu/views.py
line 62 
form.is_valid()
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not initializing the form correctly, it should be:

```
form = UserCreationForm(data=request.POST)
```